# How to get a Quant Job

Tags: career

At the end of the academic year I will graduate with a Computer Science degree (hopefully) and I would like to peruse a career in quantitative finance. What is the dest way of doing this?

Is it worth doing a doctorate like [this](http://www.findaphd.com/search/PhDDetails.aspx?CAID=384&LID=1626) from UCL or just get a job in the city with a hedge fund or bank.

Where is the best place to start looking  for quant openings, websites, reciters, or other places?

I live just south of london so commuting is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mark Joshi](http://www.markjoshi.com/) has a great collection of tips and interview questions on this topic.

Edit: A bit harder to spot, so here it is directly: http://www.markjoshi.com/downloads/advice.pdf

Comment: This link has been on our [FAQ](http://quant.stackexchange.com/faq) for a very long time.

Comment: [Broken link on the on-topic page](https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1591/39257)